# How to get count of browser open window or tab?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

> I am using JavaScript in my project.

**Problem:** In my project I used `window.open('..');` and it open a new browser window.Inside that window I have data entry form and in Parent window I have a button called **Save Record** but when user click on that button at that time **I have to check if the child window is not closed then I have to show a warning message to user.**

How can I do this using Javascript or asp.net ?

Please give me suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar - But in my case it's different because how can I check `window.open('..') is null or not` on the base of child window close?

Comment: var child = window.open(...); ... if (child.closed){ ... ?